# SFTP: log to a separate file for chrooted user

Tags: sftp, chroot

I would like to log SFTP commands to a separate file however it works only for `root` but not for chrooted user:

```
# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
...
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -l INFO
Match Group user1
   ChrootDirectory /chroot
   ForceCommand internal-sftp -l INFO
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   X11Forwarding no
```

-

Default facility is AUTH according to [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sftp-server)

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/sshd.conf
auth.* /var/log/sftp.log
```

-

```
tail -F /var/log/secure /var/log/sftp.log

==> /var/log/secure <==
Dec 27 12:35:09 lab sshd[43014]: Accepted publickey for root from 192.168.1.100 port 44706 ssh2
Dec 27 12:35:09 lab sshd[43014]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 27 12:35:09 lab sshd[43014]: subsystem request for sftp

==> /var/log/sftp.log <==
Dec 27 12:35:09 lab internal-sftp[43016]: session opened for local user root from [192.168.1.100]
Dec 27 12:35:10 lab internal-sftp[43016]: opendir "/root/"
Dec 27 12:35:10 lab internal-sftp[43016]: closedir "/root/"
Dec 27 12:35:27 lab internal-sftp[43016]: session closed for local user root from [192.168.1.100]

==> /var/log/secure <==
Dec 27 12:35:27 lab sshd[43014]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.100: 11: disconnected by user
Dec 27 12:35:27 lab sshd[43014]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Dec 27 12:35:31 lab sshd[43017]: Accepted password for user1 from 192.168.1.100 port 44708 ssh2
Dec 27 12:35:31 lab sshd[43017]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user1 by (uid=0)
Dec 27 12:35:31 lab sshd[43019]: subsystem request for sftp
Dec 27 12:35:31 lab sshd[43020]: session opened for local user user1 from [192.168.1.100]
Dec 27 12:35:31 lab sshd[43020]: opendir "/"
Dec 27 12:35:31 lab sshd[43020]: closedir "/"
```

**EDIT: Mon Dec 30 11:40:18 GMT 2013**

System: CentOS 6.5

I added the following options however events are still logged to the /var/log/secure log file:

```
# id user1
uid=501(user1) gid=501(user1) groups=501(user1)
# mkdir /chroot/dev
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/sshd.conf
$AddUnixListenSocket /chroot/dev/log
auth.* /chroot/dev/sftp.log
# service rsyslog restart
Shutting down system logger:                               [  OK  ]
Starting system logger:                                    [  OK  ]
# ll /chroot/dev/
total 0
srw-rw-rw- 1 root   root   0 Dec 30 11:44 log
-rw------- 1 nobody nobody 0 Dec 30 11:39 sftp.log
```

Comment: did you try using Match User user1? because you wrote Match Group but user1 isn't a group but is a user

Comment: What is your definition for the group "user1"?

Comment: Still doesn't work on CentOS 6.5 even after applying the "accepted" answer and all the comments. The sshd is still opening /dev/log before it does chroot. WTF...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c03154341) I believe you meet one of three criteria for having detailed logging of chrooted sftp users:

- detailed logging must be configured in the sftpd config. You appear to have done so using the *"ForceCommand internal-sftp -l INFO"* directive.
- a log file must be specified inside of the chrooted directory, as a chrooted user does not have permission to write to the /var/log directory.
- a logging socket must be added to rsyslogd to facilitate logging to the new log file.

Comparing other links such as [this generic instruction](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging) and [this CentOS instruction](http://matthewcmcmillan.blogspot.se/2012/03/detailed-logging-for-chrooted-sftp.html?m=1) it appears that the exact configuration varies slightly between distros with regards to preferred custom directory names for the logging path, the exact file where to place the logging socket config and the expression of the logging socket config.

**[EDIT]** `Mon Dec 30 21:50:00 GMT 2013`

I don't have access to a CentOS at the moment but found what appears to be an excellent guide in a link in the CentOS-page above. The link is broken but I could access the page through the [Waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120409201231/http://www.bigmite.com/blog/2010/05/19/chroot-sftp-using-openssh-and-logging/). But as the guide seems at risk of disappearing, I'm now going to blatantly copy the parts relevant to your questions in a magnificent quote below. Hopefully it will help you, but as said at the moment I have no means of testing on the distro you use.

It appears you have done some things differently, so fingers crossed you will strike gold below.

--Start quote from [bigmite.com in Waybackmachine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120409201231/http://www.bigmite.com/blog/2010/05/19/chroot-sftp-using-openssh-and-logging/)--

---

## Chroot Configuration

In this example I am going to set up a group of users that require SFTP access only (no SSH) and are going to copy files to a filesystem on a SFTP server. The location of the filesystem is going to be `/sftp` and users will reside in seperate folders under here.

Initially a new group should be created, here called `“sftpuser”`. Each user that requires SFTP access will be placed in this group.

The `sshd_config` (on debian in `/etc/ssh`) should be edited and the following added on the end:-

```
Match group sftpuser
 ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
 X11Forwarding no
 AllowTcpForwarding no
 ForceCommand internal-sftp -l VERBOSE -f LOCAL6
```

This does the following:-

1. Forces all users connecting via ssh on port 22 to have sftp only
2. Runs their sftp session in a chroot jail in directory `/sftp/$USER`
3. Prevents them TCP of X11 forwarding connections
4. Runs the internal sftp server getting it to log verbose and to syslog channel name `LOCAL6`

Now a user should be created, without creating a home directory and in the default group `sftpuser`. On ubuntu you can enter:-

*(Line break added by me for readability! /E)*

```
adduser --home / --gecos "First Test SFTP User" --group sftpuser --no-create-home
--shell /bin/false testuser1
```

The reason the home directory is set to `/` is that the sftp will chroot to `/sftp/testuser1`. Next the users home directory will need creating:-

```
mkdir /sftp/testuser1
chmod 755 /sftp/testuser1
mkdir /sftp/tstuser1/in
mkdir /sftp/testuser1/out
chown testuser1 /sftp/testuse1/in
```

Note that the directory structure and permissions that you set may differ depending on your requirements. The users password should be set, and sshd restarted (on debian `service ssh restart`).

Now it should be possible to sftp files to the host using the command line sftp tool, but it should not be possible to ssh to the server as user `testuser1`.

## Logging

You will see verbose sftp logging being produced in the `/var/logmessages` for each chroot’ed user, where by default this should go to the `daemon.log`. The reason for this is that the chroot’ed sftp process can not open `/dev/log` as this is not within the chrooted filesystem.

There are two fixes to this problem, depending on the filesystem configuration.

### If the users sftp directory /sftp/user is on the root filesystem

You can create a hard link to mimic the device:-

```
mkdir /sftp/testuser1/dev
chmod 755 /sftp/testuser1/dev
ln /dev/log /sftp/testuser1/dev/log
```

### If the users sftp directory is NOT on the root filesystem

First syslog or rsyslog will need use an additonal logging socket within the users filesystem. For my example `/sftp` is a seperate sftp filesystem.

**For Redhat**

On redhat syslog is used, so I altered `/etc/sysconfif/syslog` so that the line:-

```
SYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-m 0"
```

reads:-

```
SYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-m 0 -a /sftp/sftp.log.socket
```

Finally the syslog daemon needs to be told to log messages for `LOCAL6` to the `/var/log/sftp.log` file, so the following was added to `/etc/syslog.conf`:-

```
# For SFTP logging
local6.*                        /var/log/sftp.log
```

and syslog was restarted.

**For Ubuntu Lucid**

On Ubuntu lucid I created `/etc/rsyslog.d/sshd.conf` containing:-

```
# Create an additional socket for some of the sshd chrooted users.
$AddUnixListenSocket /sftp/sftp.log.socket
# Log internal-sftp in a separate file
:programname, isequal, "internal-sftp" -/var/log/sftp.log
:programname, isequal, "internal-sftp" ~
```

… and restarted rsyslogd.

**Creating log devices for users**

Now for each user a `/dev/log device` needs creating:-

```
mkdir /sftp/testuser1/dev
chmod 755 /sftp/testuser1/dev
ln /sftp/sftp.log.socket /sftp/testuser1/dev/log
```

---

--End quote--

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've made the recommended changes however it still doesn't work (please see my edit - `EDIT: Mon Dec 30 11:40:18 GMT 2013`).

Comment: Unfortunately none of these configuration options work for me but thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thanks! I tried answering as I have the very same task to solve in my backlog, albeit for BSD. I will return to this question when I do and give it a tried and tested shot.

Comment: this worked with very minor adaptation for Suse 12.1.

Comment: although the _hard_ link from the user's chrooted space ( `/sftp/user/dev/log`) to the shared socket (`/sftp/sftp.log.socket`) is [required](https://askubuntu.com/a/935027/454119), this seems to work and the internal subsystem is able to write to the linked log device (which saves lots of lines in the `rsyslog` config file)