# SFTP and syslog-ng custom logging format

Tags: ssh, unix, sftp, syslog-ng

I have modified sshd_config and syslog-ng configs to log sftp connections into separate files.
Now I would like to create custom logging like:

[date] [source_ip] has downloaded the [filename] [size]

for the config I have used: [SFTP: log to a separate file for chrooted user](https://serverfault.com/questions/563739/sftp-log-to-a-separate-file-for-chrooted-user)

Answer (score 1):

With syslog-ng, you can reformat a log message, and even do more complex things, but it depends on what SSHD actually logs about the connections. Can you post some sample logs about the SFTP downloads to see what information is available?

Robert

Comment: I use either INFO or DEBUG for the logs. Regarding reformating - tha'ts my exact question, how do I reformat the logs so it stores information in the following format: [date] [source_ip] has downloaded the [filename] [size]

Comment: ok I think I got it: http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/csv-parser.html