# Format SFTP Logs to have Username on Each Entry

Tags: ssh, logging, sftp, rsyslog

I'm running a production server (Debian 10, standard OpenSSH package) that has Pure-FTPD running for legacy connections and SFTP for all our current connections. The SFTP server is setup with a chroot jail that logs via a bound device in the user's chroot jail. This is picked up by rsyslog and sent to /var/log/sftp.log, after which I am using logstash to parse that file and forward everything to a visualization server for our superusers. The superusers log into the visualization to see all SFTP and FTP/FTPS logs in one place.

The pure-ftpd logs are formatted in a way that our superusers like:

```
pure-ftpd: (testuser@hostname) [NOTICE] /home/ftpusers/testuser//outbound/testfile.pdf downloaded  (1765060 bytes, 5989.55KB/sec)
```

This is great, because in a single line it shows the exact user and exact file that they uploaded or downloaded. However, for SFTP the situation is not as nice:

```
internal-sftp[8848]: session opened for local user testuser from [{ip_address}]
internal-sftp[8848]: opendir "/inbound"
internal-sftp[8848]: realpath "/inbound/."
internal-sftp[8848]: open "/inbound/testfile.pdf" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0666
internal-sftp[8848]: close "/inbound/testfile.pdf" bytes read 0 written 1734445
```

In this case, the logs are easy to follow. `testuser` logs in, writes file, done. BUT we have many users logging in at a time, and logs from multiple instances of internal-sftp can occur at once. If this happens, the only way to track the activity for a user is to search for the username `testuser`, find the process ID that is logged (`8848` in the example above) then find any messages that have that process ID. Many users are logging in via a cronjob, so this happens every 2 minutes or so...when we have 300 users logging in at regular intervals, you can imagine that hunting through this many process ID's would be a pain.

## My Question

***Is there a way to preface each log message from sftp-internal with the name of the user that is generating the log? This would have to work in a chroot jail.*** I cannot find anything about how to modify the message that rsyslog generates to include the username.

I would like to see something similar from my SFTP logs:

```
internal-sftp[8848]: (testuser) open "/inbound/testfile.pdf" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0666
internal-sftp[8848]: (testuser) close "/inbound/testfile.pdf" bytes read 0 written 1734445
```

### Current State of Configuration

My process chain goes:

ssh -> sftp-internal -> rsyslog (on local3.*) -> file /var/log/sftp.log -> logstash -> export to visualization server

Excerpt from my chroot group in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Match Group sftpusers 
        ChrootDirectory %h
        AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -f local3 -l INFO
        # ForceCommand internal-sftp -l VERBOSE
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
```

and my /etc/rsyslog.d/sftp.conf

```
local3.*        -/var/log/sftp.log
```

### Similar Questions:

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/563739/sftp-log-to-a-separate-file-for-chrooted-user) is about SFTP logging to separate files, but it mentions [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120409201231/http://www.bigmite.com/blog/2010/05/19/chroot-sftp-using-openssh-and-logging/) waybackmachine entry for an old article that included pretty-formatting SFTP log entries to look like standard xferlogs. The article mentions a Perl script (holy grail) that will format it for you, but alas, the link is dead. I could write a Python or Perl script that finds the specific message for transfers, grabs the process id, and reverse searches to find the user, then prints a reformatted xfer message with the username out to a file. But surely someone has solved this problem before and has a better solution.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build a solution with Python and systemd. This is *very* quick-and-dirty but works for my purposes. I take in a sftp-internal log file and dump it to a reformatted one. I *do not modify* the original in case this formatter makes any errors.

## The Python Script

This logs out to rsyslog for monitoring and responds to SEGINT from systemd. Yes, this should use something better than a list, but python has no ring buffers or formal queueing system built in (send me a comment if there's something I'm missing). Either way...this ain't C!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import logging
import re
import sys
import time


class SFTPLogFormatter:

    def __init__(self, infile: str, outfile: str):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        stdout_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)8s | %(message)s'))
        self.logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

        self.infile = open(infile, 'r')

        # append to file and keep only 1 lines in a write buffer (write almost
        # immediately)
        self.outfile = open(outfile, 'a', 1)

    def start(self):
        try:
            self.logger.info('starting formatter')
            self.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.logger.warning('SIGINT received, gracefully exiting')
            self.stop()

    @staticmethod
    def tail_file(file_obj):
        while True:
            line = file_obj.readline()
            # sleep if file hasn't been updated
            if not line:
                time.sleep(1)
                continue

            yield line

    def run(self):
        self.infile.seek(0, 2)  # jump to end of file for `tail -f` type behavior
        lines_read = []
        for line in self.tail_file(self.infile): # tail a file like `tail -f`
            lines_read.insert(0, line) # treat the list like a stack
            lines_read = lines_read[:2000] # trim stack since python does not have ring buffers

            modifyline_match = re.match(r'(.*)\[(\d+)\]: (open|close|remove name) (.*)', line) 
            if not modifyline_match:
                self.logger.info(line)
                self.outfile.write(line)
                continue

            modify_line_procid = modifyline_match.group(2)

            self.logger.debug(f'searching for session open statement for open|close file match string: \"{modifyline_match.group(0)}\"')
            open_session_regex = rf'.*\[{modify_line_procid}\]: session opened for local user (.*) from.*'
            open_session_match = None
            for prevline in lines_read[1:]:
                open_session_match = re.match(open_session_regex, prevline)
                if open_session_match:
                    self.logger.debug(f'found session open string: \"{open_session_match.group(0)}\"')
                    break
            else:
                # we found nothing
                self.logger.debug('could not find open session string for: \"{modifyline_match.group(0)}\"')
                continue

            modify_line_start = modifyline_match.group(1)
            modify_line_operator = modifyline_match.group(3)
            modify_line_details = modifyline_match.group(4)

            username = open_session_match.group(1)

            log_str = f'{modify_line_start}[{modify_line_procid}]: (user={username}) {modify_line_operator} {modify_line_details}\n'
            self.logger.info(log_str)
            self.outfile.write(log_str)

    def stop(self):
        self.logger.info('cleaning up')
        try:
            self.infile.close()
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f'failure while closing infile: {e}')

        try:
            self.outfile.close()
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f'failure while closing outfile: {e}')

        self.logger.info('exit')
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    infile = sys.argv[1]
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
    service = SFTPLogFormatter(infile, outfile)
    service.start()
```

## Service File

The following service file was created and enabled in systemd.

```
[Unit]
Description=Format log messages from sftp to have the username on any file reads, writes, and deletes, making multi-user logs much easier to read.
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/admin/services/format_sftp_logs_with_username.py /var/log/sftp.log /var/log/sftp_with_usernames.log
KillSignal=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## Results

This results in the following log messages. Notice the (user=XYZ) additions.

```
Feb 11 21:22:01 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: session opened for local user testuser from [127.0.0.1]
Feb 11 21:22:02 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: opendir "/"
Feb 11 21:22:02 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: closedir "/"
Feb 11 21:22:05 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: opendir "/inbound"
Feb 11 21:22:05 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: closedir "/inbound"
Feb 11 21:22:10 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: opendir "/inbound/"
Feb 11 21:22:10 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: closedir "/inbound/"
Feb 11 21:22:12 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: (user=testuser) open "/inbound/mailhog-deployment.yaml" flags READ mode 0666
Feb 11 21:22:12 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: (user=testuser) close "/inbound/mailhog-deployment.yaml" bytes read 815 written 0
Feb 11 21:22:13 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: opendir "/inbound/"
Feb 11 21:22:13 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: closedir "/inbound/"
Feb 11 21:22:14 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: opendir "/inbound/"
Feb 11 21:22:14 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: closedir "/inbound/"
Feb 11 21:22:14 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: (user=testuser) remove name "/inbound/mailhog-deployment.yaml"
Feb 11 21:22:18 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: (user=testuser) open "/inbound/mailhog-deployment.yaml" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0644
Feb 11 21:22:18 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: (user=testuser) close "/inbound/mailhog-deployment.yaml" bytes read 0 written 815
Feb 11 21:22:19 ip-10-20-0-96 internal-sftp[18241]: session closed for local user testuser from [127.0.0.1]
```

## Limitations

The buffer has a 2000 line look-behind to hunt for the process id. Bump that up if you have dozens or hundreds of users logging in at a given instant. Otherwise this should cover most server's needs.